# Passing parameters to a custom class on initialization

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, init

I have a class `Message` with two attributes, `name` and `message`, and another class `MessageController` with two text fields, `nameField` and `messageField`.
I want to make an instance of `Message` in `MessageController`, passing these two attributes as arguments.

Right now, I am doing this:

```
 Message *messageIns = [[Message alloc] init];
 messageIns.name = nameField;
 messageIns.message = MessageField;
```

How can I pass the values at the creation of an instance?
I tried to redefine `init` in Message.m, but I don't know how do that.

```
-(id)init{
    if((self=[super init])){

    }
    return self;
}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You have to create a custom initializer.

```
-(id)initWithName:(NSString *)name_ message:(NSString *)message_ 
{
     self = [super init];
     if (self) {
         self.name = name_;
         self.message = message_;
     }
     return self;
}
```

of course this assumes your parameters are of NSString type and that you have your properties set correctly ;)

Comment: Thank you very much . And how should i call the method ? Message *messageIns = [[Message alloc] initWithName:name,message]; ??sorry but i'm a nob in this domain .

Comment: call it like this: `Message *messageIns = [[Message alloc] initWithName:someNameString message:someMessageString]`

Comment: also add 
`-(id)initWithName:(NSString *)name_ message:(NSString *)message_ ; `
in the Message.h

Comment: don't use self.thing inside the init. Use _thing