# How to use Initializer list in objective C

Tags: c++, iphone, ios, objective-c

I have worked on c++, there we used initializer list like below to initialize the constructor of base class.

```
Derived::Derived(int x):Base(x) { 
    cout << "B's Constructor called";
}
```

How to acheive the same action in objective C. How to pass value to base (super) class while initlizing. Is it possible?

thanx.

Comment: Do you mean the sequence of init method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use `[super init];` to initialize all your super classes. It does what you require.

Comment: how to pass value while initilizing?

Comment: Create custom initializer.

Comment: The link may help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6084802/passing-parameters-to-a-custom-class-on-initialization

Answer (score 2):

Here we use super to call the Base Class Constructor. For example:
Lets say we have a base class, and has this initiator method

```
// Base .h
- (id)initWithName:(NSString *)name;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *name;

// Base.m
- (id)initWithName:(NSString *)name
 {
   self = [super init];
   if(self){
     self.name = name;
   }
  return self
 }

 // Derived.h
- (id)initWithName:(NSString *)name;

// Derived.m
- (id)initWithName:(NSString *)name
 {
   self = [super initWithName:name];
    return self;
 }

// This is how we can create an object of Derived class
Derived *derived = [[Derived alloc]initWithName:@"foo"];
```

Comment: So base class do we need to write init methods corresponding to ivars, init:(id)value : (NSString8)...

Comment: No. You can call another super method as well from one init method in Base class.

Comment: I got the same doubts... it helps... :)

Answer (score 0):

```
- (instancetype)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
       // your code here
    }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Objective-C, there is no constructor, the subclass needs to call parent's class's init method explicitly. like `[super init];`

Here is a good article to describe the initialiser of Objective C objects. [Object Initialization](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Initialization/Initialization.html)